# Add new key/value in spring cloud config

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I have a use case where some properties file are exposed as service using spring cloud config, now let's say someone add new key-value to a properties file then how should we read the new key-value in config-client after refresh as the bean present has no mapping available?

Also how to map new properties file?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a wrapper kind of class which takes care of any properties and use the wrapper to fetch the values of the arguments. For example,

```
@Component
public class ApplicationProperties {

  private Properties properties = new Properties();

  private Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  public ApplicationProperties(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  public String getProperty(String name) {
    return getPropertyFromEnvContext(name);
  }

  public String getProperty(String name, String defaultValue) {
    String value = getProperty(name);
    return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
  }

  private String getPropertyFromEnvContext(String name) {
    if (environment == null) {
        return properties.getProperty(name);
    }
    return properties.getProperty(name, environment.getProperty(name));
  }
}
```

Then, inject this properties class in the beans and use `getProperty` method to fetch the value of the property. You have to write the logic for the key.

For example, in my use case,

```
String propertyKey = format("topics.%s.%s.%s", someVariable, someOtherVariable, priority);
properties.getProperty(propertyKey);
```

Comment: Fine. Let's say I have a new XML file added in my git repo then how should I map it to a resource in spring application as application won't be knowing the name before hand.